# python does not produce log file

Tags: python, ubuntu, logging

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/achref/Documents/auto-test/NeoPosTestLog.log',level=logging.INFO, filemode='w', format="[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s")
logging.info("ChromeBrowser Test setup")
```

When I execute the above script the log file does not appear. I've tested it on Windows and it works fine but it does not work on Ubuntu 18.04. I am using `python 3.6.5`

Comment: Do you get any kind of error message or is the log file simply not appearing? Because i tested your snippet, with the slight modification of mode 'a', and that seems to work like intended.

Comment: i don't get any error, the script works fine, just the log don't appear

Comment: Hhm ... i suspect permission shenanigans. To check this you can try to `touch` the log file and see if that produces any errors or try something like `sudo chmod 755 <logDirPath>` to set less restrictive permission on the target directory and run the script again.

Comment: i tried it and nothing happened